# Docker Desktop - Container not showing / disappearing / missing / deleted

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, desktop, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 and Docker Desktop on Windows 10.
Started creating containers and everything showed up as expected in Docker Desktop.

After restarting the PC all my Docker containers where gone and I had to setup every container again.

So the time goes buy and I'm going to sleep and shutdown my PC.

Voila next day -> all Docker Desktop Containers are gone - again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a PC with 16 GB of RAM and I saw that nearly 90% was in use when using WSL and Docker.

So I upgraded to 64 GB of RAM and the issue seemed to be resolved - that was a hard to learn lesson.